# How to change the axis and legend on loess.ancova function

Tags: r, loess, ancova

I am trying to do an ANCOVA test of a specific dataset using fANCOVA package and the loess.ancova function.

```
loess.ancova(y=dt$response,x=dt$var1,group=dt$species,family= "gaussian",method="Speckman", plot = T)
```

After calling the code I get a plot similar to this[image]

How can I change the legend and the axis names? I tried using

```
loess.ancova(y,x,group,...,plot=T, xlab="var1", ylab="response")
```

but nothing changed, since that failed I have no idea how to even try to change the legend

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one possibility is to save the result of your `loess.ancova` call:

```
result <- loess.ancova(y=dt$response,
                       x=dt$var1,
                       group=dt$species,
                       family= "gaussian",
                       method="Speckman",
                       plot = T
                       )
```

Inspection of the result with `str(result)` shows that it contains an item "smooth.fit":

```
> str(result)
List of 2
 $ linear.fit: num [1:3, 1] 5.88 -3.01 -6.1
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "(Intercept)" "group2" "group3"
  .. ..$ : NULL
 $ smooth.fit:List of 18
  ..$ n        : int 245
  ..$ fitted   : num [1:245
## [truncated]
```

... which you can plot, using the desired base `plot()` arguments:

```
result$smooth.fit |> plot(xlab = 'my x-axis label', ...)
```